# Сортировка метаданных мп3 файла по примеру

Tags: java, html, сортировка, mp3

Я считал метаданные мп3 файлов в html файл, вот собственно код

```
public static void readFiles(File baseDirectory){

        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            if(baseDirectory.isDirectory()) {
                for (File fileloop : baseDirectory.listFiles()) {
                    if(fileloop.isFile()) {

                        InputStream input = new FileInputStream(fileloop);
                        ContentHandler handler = new DefaultHandler();
                        Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
                        Parser parser = new Mp3Parser();
                        ParseContext parseCtx = new ParseContext();
                        parser.parse(input, handler, metadata, parseCtx);
                        input.close();
                        String[] metadataNames = metadata.names();
                        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------");
                        sb.append("<br>");
                        sb.append("Title: ") .append(metadata.get("title"));
                        sb.append("<br>");
                        sb.append("Artist: ").append(metadata.get("xmpDM:artist"));
                        sb.append("<br>");
                        sb.append("Album : ").append(metadata.get("xmpDM:album"));
                        sb.append("<br>");
                        sb.append("Duration : ").append(toMinutes(metadata.get("xmpDM:duration")));
                        sb.append("<br>");
                        sb.append("Path : ");
                        sb.append("<a href= > ");
                        sb.append(fileloop.getAbsolutePath());
                        sb.append("</a>");
                        String result = sb.toString();
                        toHtml(result);
                    }
                    else{
                        readFiles(fileloop);
                    }
                }
            }
```

А вот так нужно отсортировать(все метаданные получены)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я не знаю как файл скинуть, скину  скрин
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а можно подкрепить html?

Comment: Да конечно, выше

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поскольку фактически вы сбросили обычный текстовый файл и пишите, что вся метаинформация уже получена, то его (обычный текстовый файл) и возьмем за исходные данные. 
Возможно, мне не совсем понятна суть проблемы, поэтому все уточняющие вопросы прошу писать в комментариях к ответу.
Итак, чтобы свободно оперировать данными, которые сейчас содержатся в файле, нам нужно превратить их в объекты, а уже с объектами проблем не возникнет.
Для начала создадим класс, описывающий все необходимые нам данные:

import java.util.Objects;

```
public class Mp3Data implements Comparable<Mp3Data>{

    private String artist;
    private String album;
    private String title;
    private String duration;
    private String path;

    public boolean map(final String key, final String value) {        
        switch (key) {
            case "Artist": this.artist=value; break;
            case "Album": this.album=value; break;
            case "Title": this.title=value; break;
            case "Duration": this.duration=value; break;
            case "Path": this.path=value; break;
            default:return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public String getArtist() {
        return artist;
    }

    public String getAlbum() {
        return album;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return title + " " + duration + " (" + path + ")";
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 3;
        hash = 71 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.artist);
        hash = 71 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.album);
        hash = 71 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.title);
        hash = 71 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.duration);
        hash = 71 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.path);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Mp3Data other = (Mp3Data) obj;
        if (!Objects.equals(this.artist, other.artist)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.album, other.album)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.title, other.title)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.duration, other.duration)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.path, other.path)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Mp3Data{" + "artist=" + artist + ", album=" + album + ", "
                + "title=" + title + ", duration=" + duration + ", path=" + path + '}';
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Mp3Data mp3Data) {
        int compare = artist.compareTo(mp3Data.getArtist());
        if (compare!=0) return compare;
        else return album.compareTo(mp3Data.getAlbum());
    }

}
```

А теперь нам надо переписать наши данные в экземпляры этого класса. Для этого создаем еще один класс (в этом примере это ридер файла, вычитывающий информацию построчно):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

public class TxtReader {

    private final String fileName;
    private final Set<String> fieldExist;
    private final List<Mp3Data> mp3Datas;

    public TxtReader(final String fileName) {
        this.mp3Datas = new ArrayList<>();
        this.fieldExist = new HashSet<>();
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    public List<Mp3Data> read() throws FileNotFoundException {
        final Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        while (sc.hasNext()) map(sc.nextLine());
        return mp3Datas;
    }

    private void map(final String line) {

        final int index = line.indexOf(':');
        if (index <= 0) return;
        final String key = line.substring(0, index).trim();
        final String value = line.substring(index + 1, line.length()).trim();

        if (fieldExist.contains(key) || fieldExist.isEmpty()) {
            mp3Datas.add(new Mp3Data());
            fieldExist.clear();
        }

        fieldExist.add(key);        
        mp3Datas.get(mp3Datas.size() - 1).map(key, value);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        List<Mp3Data> result = new TxtReader("mp3.txt").read();
        Collections.sort(result);

        String artist=null;
        String album=null;        

    for (Mp3Data mp3Data : result) {
        if (!mp3Data.getArtist().equals(artist)) 
            System.out.println(mp3Data.getArtist());
        if (!mp3Data.getAlbum().equals(album)) 
            System.out.println(mp3Data.getAlbum());
        System.out.println(mp3Data.getDescription());
        artist = mp3Data.getArtist();
        album = mp3Data.getAlbum();
    }
    }

}
```

Последний метод main создан только для демонстрации того, как этим пользоваться.
В результате мы получим коллекцию с объектами класса Mp3Data, содержащую всю информацию из файла. Теперь читайте ее как вам угодно. Если важен порядок элементов в коллекции, то эторешается добавлением компараторов. Допишите это в в комментарии к ответу и я покажу, как это реализовать.

Comment: Дело вот в чем, мои данные считанные с мп3 файлов хранятся в строке, а потом я эту строку записываю в html файл, на скрине видно что у меня получилось, но мне надо что бы было отсортировано  как на скрине выше

Comment: То , что у вас уже есть - это второй скрин, насколько я понял. В классе TxtReader  есть метод read. По сути сейчас он каждую строку, отоображенную на вашем скрине-результате передает в метод map. Результат работы хранится в коллекции mp3Datas. Передавайте в метод map построчно свои стринги и получите коллекцию с объектами.Можно переписать соответстующим образм метод read, можно напрямую. А уже имея коллекцию объектов, с ними можно сделать все, что угодно без особого труда. На каком именно этапе у вас сложности?

Comment: Я создал классы которые описывают данные, дальше  я считаю строки с метаданными в коллекцию и что после?

Comment: Отлично, давайте определимся, что в вашем понимании "сортировка"? В нашей коллекции есть 2 объекта, каждый описывает один трек. Мы можем отсортировать данные по исполнителю, альбому, названию трека  и.т.д. для отображения объектов в нужном порядке. Либо вы хотите в пределах одного объекта получить сначала исполнителя, потом альбом, а потом строку с остальными данными , разделенными пробелом?

Comment: так там выше скрин, сначала исполнитель потом идут его альбомы, а собственно в альбомах треки с названием длительностью и путем к файлу

Comment: теперь итерируетесь по этой коллекции, вызываете у каждого полученного в ходе итерации объекта методы getArtist, getAlbum, getDescription поочередно и получаете исполнителя, альбом и остальную инфу соответсвенно. (ответ исправил)

Comment: А несовсем понятно как работает то, что исполнитель не повторяется и альбом например?

Comment: Это код не убирает никаких дубликатов. Вы получаете все, что передаете в метод map, Если вы хотите исключить из результата одинаковые песни, это довольно легко. Только надо понять по каким критериям их считать одинаковыми (совпадения названия и исполнителя или только названия или еще чего -то)

Comment: У меня например есть несколько альбомов одного исполнителя надо что бы исполнитель упоминался один раз а ниже его альбомы

Comment: Для этого нужен компаратор. Ответ исправил, пробуйте...

Comment: и все это дело должно не в консоль выводиться а в html файл

Comment: Ну так выводите в html. вместо консольного вызова дергайте за свой метод, который генерит html  и передавайте ему то, что сейчас идет в консоль. Хотите - можете собрать эти данные в новую коллекцию стрингов, где уже все будет упорядочено...